# how to use pdo object created in a namespace

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces

I am trying to create a `PDO` object in a class and then use it in another file. The `PDO Object` gets created (as far as I understand) but I can not use it in the other file and I view these outputs:

> PDO Object ( )
>
> connection successful.
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   app\db\Connect::query() in /var/www/html/pdoTest/index.php:25 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/pdoTest/index.php on line 25

My code is as following:

> index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$con = new \app\db\Connect();
if (!$con)
  {
    echo 'no PDO object available.';
  }else{
    echo 'connection successful.' . '<br>';
  }
```

> connect.php

```
<?php
namespace app\db;
use PDO;

class Connect
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    // set the connection variables
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'pdoposts';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'root';

    // create the DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' .$dbname;

    // create PDO connection
    try {
      $con = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
      print_r($con);
      echo '<br>';
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $con;  
  }
}
```

I have searched all over `stackoverflow` and other parts of internet but as it seems I am out of luck understanding what my problem is in using the created `PDO` object. Would you please help me understand it?

Comment: You use a class constructor like a function, which doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, Sorry I didn't know about that. Thank you very much for the hint. God bless you.